# Select Maximum value from a table field with criteria

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

This gets the maximum number from the `Voucher_Number` field of Table `tblInvoiceLog`

I want to get the maximum number but only where the field `Source` in the same table is equal to `Me.Source.Value`

I am not sure how can I add this condition please advise:

CODE:

```vb
Private Sub Source_AfterUpdate()    

    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset, MyVal
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    rs.Open "SELECT MAX(Voucher_Number) from tblInvoiceLog", CurrentProject.Connection
    rs.MoveFirst
    MyVal = rs.Fields(0).Value
    Me.Voucher_Number.Value = MyVal + 1
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: I'd recommend using a paramaterized query. such as defined on a [MSDN site](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208916(v=office.12).aspx)  simply adding the criteria to the where clause would work, but it's not the right approach long term.  IMO better to learn an approach that avoids SQL injection so you don't fall into bad habits now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add a WHERE clause to your SQL query

```vb
Private Sub Source_AfterUpdate()    

    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset, MyVal

    Dim SQL as String

    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

    ' If Source field is STRING type
    SQL = "SELECT MAX(Voucher_Number) from tblInvoiceLog WHERE [Source]='" & Me.Source.Value & "'"

    ' If Source field is NUMBER type
    SQL = "SELECT MAX(Voucher_Number) from tblInvoiceLog WHERE [Source]=" & Me.Source.Value 

    rs.Open SQL, CurrentProject.Connection
    rs.MoveFirst
    MyVal = rs.Fields(0).Value
    Me.Voucher_Number.Value = MyVal + 1
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Private Sub Source_AfterUpdate()

```
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset, MyVal
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
rs.Open "SELECT MAX(Voucher_Number) from tblInvoiceLog where source="&me.source.value, CurrentProject.Connection
rs.MoveFirst
MyVal = rs.Fields(0).Value
Me.Voucher_Number.Value = MyVal + 1
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
```

End Sub